# Why do browsers have a large latency between input and response?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser

I used an Arduino controller to measure the response time of browsers.
I measure the time from a keypress to a visual response on the screen (specifically, displaying a white square on the screen).

When using a native application (OpenSesame) I get an average latency of 12ms which is expected, considering frame rate.
When using browsers I get around 40ms in the good case (Chrome) and up to 65ms in the worse cases (Firefox, IE).

In devtools the response is see as happening within a single frame (less than 17ms).

The code that I use in the browsers is super simple - just an eventListener that applies a class to the body on keydown, and removes it after 100ms.

CSS:

```
body {background:#000}
.show {background:#fff}
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    document.body.classList.add('show');
    setTimeout(() => document.body.classList.remove('show'), 100);
});
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?
Is there any way to improve response times?

Comment: How does the title relate to the question?

Comment: @JaredFarrish edited to clarify. Is this better?